# How to determine processed database table rows of a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, analytics

Question in short: how can I get a list of row IDs of rows processed when a query is processed?

Edit note: I am not looking for returned rows. When a user has 5 posts on Facebook and I do a '''SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user=Mark ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1''' I know, that the returned number will be 1, but I'd like to know how many rows have been processed (in this case without indices, probably all rows). And I am primarily looking at SELECT statements.

Hello,

I am currently working on a project that aims in the direction of data aging. I.e., we are trying to determine which tuples are accessed regularly and which are not.
We've got a decent workload (i.e., a query log of the system) with the corresponding data and would like to know, what rows have been processed.

Besides the question, what rows we're also interested in what attributes, but that can be done parsing the query (projection, join attributes, and where conditions).
Leaving the question open how to get the actually processed rows.

We are aware that many queries will (let's assume there are no indices) process all rows, because there is a where-condition that requires a full table scan.
We are aware of that problem, but still wan't to find out, which rows have been accessed.

My final question is now: How can we achieve that?

I have been looking into MySQL and Postgres but could not find sufficient information (e.g., MySQL's 'explain' just returns an estimate for the number of rows processed, but not any row IDs). I am guess that we will have to modify the source code of a DB to achieve that kind of logging (performance of that logging is not an issue, it's offline analytics).
Has anybody any recommendations how to achieve that/done that?

Edit concerning David's comment: what I am trying to achieve is to know, which tuples (looking at the given workload) are never accessed. Typical aging problem. E.g., are Facebook posts older than 2 years pretty much never views,liked,commented anymore and could thus be stored on an external (cheaper) system. Therefore we need to now, which rows are accessed regularly.

Comment: Have you considered `SELECT COUNT(*) FORM posts WHERE user='Mark'`

Comment: First - such metric will not be usefull because databases work with turples not distinct rows. A DB will process a lot of unrelated rows just because one of the rows in the turple was somewhat related to the query. 
Second - you can try to alter DB cashing mechanisms to gather turple statistics as most of i/o goes throu caches.

Comment: Alternatively take the `LIMIT` off so you can find out the total number of rows in the resultset, but only read the first row from the resultset and then destoy the cursor.

Comment: Also Postgresql `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` might be helpfull - it provides the exact row count for every query plan node.

Comment: @Igor Romanchenko: Explain analyze, only returns a count. I am aware, that more rows that returned are processed, and I want to know exactly which rows. If they are processed without a need (what I doubt), I am still interested in that. But thanks for the caching advice, that's sounds like an interesting approach (let's hope DBs cache accessed tuples, not just returned tuples). :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I am not looking for the number of rows returned or anything like that.

Comment: I think that what you want to do is reasonably clear, but it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve with this. Stating that might help.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: added a note to the question. Does that help?

Comment: Hmm, that does make it sound like you're interested in identifying which rows become part of a required result set, and how that varies over time.

Comment: Not only part of the result set, in general part of the query execution. But yes, this data varies over time and we want to see how the 'working set' (set of data that is regularly accessed) is changing over time.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say anything about MySQL, but with PostgreSQL you can use the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,VERBOSE)`, the `VERBOSE` option will give you how many rows have been processed. See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/281e1/1) for an working case, the output of `EXPLAIN` is:

```
Limit (cost=17.57..17.58 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.145..0.146 rows=1 loops=1)
Output: a, b
-> Sort (cost=17.57..17.61 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.143..0.143 rows=1 loops=1)
    Output: a, b
    Sort Key: foo.a
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort Memory: 25kB
    -> Seq Scan on public.foo (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.114 rows=15 loops=1)
        Output: a, b
        Filter: (foo.b = 1)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 985
        Total runtime: 0.168 ms
```

If you look at the `Seq Scan` node, you can see it returned 15 rows, three lines bellow you see: "Rows Removed by Filter: 985", which means that it ignored (but processed) 985 rows, so you have `985+15=1000` scanned.

To actually see the processed rows, I can only think on a (kind of hacky) solution that creates a dummy function that will just send a `RAISE NOTICE/LOG/DEBUG` of a value from the processed row or even populate a temporary table (I think this is better), and call this function on a `WHERE` clause. The problem with this is that the PostgreSQL's planner may reorder the execution of the `AND`s and not execute the function call first. We can try to set functions's COST to 1, but there is no guarantee that this will **always** work. The function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logit(v anyelement)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tmp_row_process_log VALUES(v);
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$
COST 1;
```

And to use:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_row_process_log(a int);

SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE logit(a) AND b = 1
ORDER BY a
LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM tmp_row_process_log;
```

Look this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6dfcc/1) for an working solution.

Notice that with this solution you can, actually, change the planner's decision, so with the function call and without it may not be the same. You can use both solution and compare the results though.

Comment: Very interesting approach. Unfortunately, editing the given queries will be quite a hard problem since the given workloads consists of thousands of queries. :-/

Comment: @Bouncner: you could use the [`auto_explain`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module to generate the plan automatically without changing the statements. That will however slow down your system drastically I would assume.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really willing to tweak the source code, you can do the following in PostgreSQL.

First of all, some notes:

- It is a really **bad idea** to do that, it is useful only for educational purposes. First, because it will slow things down, second because it can crash your server (I did not tested properly)
- I have tried the following with PostgreSQL 9.2, it should work with other versions, I just did not tried.

Now, the idea is, first, to create a function to dump a tuple to a string. To make it easy, I've created a file named `src/include/debugtuple.h` (inside pg source) with the following:

```
#ifndef _DEBUGTUPLE_H_
#define _DEBUGTUPLE_H_

#include "postgres.h"

#include "access/relscan.h"
#include "executor/execdebug.h"
#include "utils/rel.h"

static void InitScanRelation(SeqScanState *node, EState *estate);
static TupleTableSlot *SeqNext(SeqScanState *node);

static char *
ExecBuildSlotValueDescription(TupleTableSlot *slot, int maxfieldlen)
{
    StringInfoData buf;
    TupleDesc   tupdesc = slot->tts_tupleDescriptor;
    int         i;

    /* Make sure the tuple is fully deconstructed */
    slot_getallattrs(slot);

    initStringInfo(&buf);

    appendStringInfoChar(&buf, '(');

    for (i = 0; i < tupdesc->natts; i++)
    {
        char       *val;
        int         vallen;

        if (slot->tts_isnull[i])
            val = "null";
        else
        {
            Oid         foutoid;
            bool        typisvarlena;

            getTypeOutputInfo(tupdesc->attrs[i]->atttypid,
                              &foutoid, &typisvarlena);
            val = OidOutputFunctionCall(foutoid, slot->tts_values[i]);
        }

        if (i > 0)
            appendStringInfoString(&buf, ", ");

        /* truncate if needed */
        vallen = strlen(val);
        if (vallen <= maxfieldlen)
            appendStringInfoString(&buf, val);
        else
        {
            vallen = pg_mbcliplen(val, vallen, maxfieldlen);
            appendBinaryStringInfo(&buf, val, vallen);
            appendStringInfoString(&buf, "...");
        }
    }

    appendStringInfoChar(&buf, ')');

    return buf.data;
}

#endif
```

Now, you will have to edit two files located at `src/backend/executor/`, the `nodeSeqscan.c` and `nodeIndexscan.c`, on both, include the file created above, with the following (on the beginning of the file):

```
#include "debugtuple.h"
```

At `nodeSeqscan.c`, find the `SeqNext` function and edit it to match the following (add just those two lines):

```
static TupleTableSlot *
SeqNext(SeqScanState *node)
{
    [...]
        ExecClearTuple(slot);

    /* ADD THE TWO FOLLOWING LINES: */
    if (slot && slot->tts_tuple)
        elog(NOTICE, "Seq Scan processed: %s", ExecBuildSlotValueDescription(slot, 1000));
    return slot;
}
```

Now, do the same at `nodeIndexscan.c` with the function `IndexNext`:

```
static TupleTableSlot *
IndexNext(IndexScanState *node)
{
    [...]
    while ((tuple = index_getnext(scandesc, direction)) != NULL)
    {
        [...]

        /* ADD THE TWO FOLLOWING LINES: */
        if (slot && slot->tts_tuple)
            elog(NOTICE, "Index Scan processed: %s", ExecBuildSlotValueDescription(slot, 1000));
        return slot;
    }

    ...
    return ExecClearTuple(slot);
}
```

At last, go to the root of source code and re-compile it:

```
make && make install
```

Now, this modified version will raise a NOTICE message on every tuple it process with `seqscan` or `indexscan` (and only those). You can modify the line with `elog` function call to do whatever you want.

Have fun.

Comment: Wow, this answer looks incredibly helpful. Gonna try to implement that. Thanks a lot MatheusOl!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question because it brings to light an essential property of relational database technology.

SQL is not a procedural language, it is a declarative language. Using it with a client procedural language (like Java, C#, php) puts you in a strange realm between declaration and procedure. The realm you inhabit is made even stranger by the fact that real-life RDBMSs are implemented in a procedural fashion.   So when writing application SQL you're living in a seam of declarative coal sandwiched between two layers of procedural rock.

You could do this data-aging query you propose with a file system, which inhabits a procedural realm. Many file systems have a date-most-recently-referenced attribute for each file.  But it's not so with RDBMSs.

When you do a `SELECT` operation you're *declaring* a particular table, a particular sequence of rows of data with each row containing certain columns.  This is sometimes called a resultset. This table is based on the contents of other tables in your RDBMS.

Please excuse me for being a purist here, but you're asking a procedural question -- what stored data did you retrieve and when? -- of a declarative system.  The question is meaningless and has no answer in the declarative realm.  It's important to understand this, because it reflects the way RDBMSs are constructed.

You could pierce the declarative veil on your RDBMS and use techniques like `EXPLAIN` to get the RDBMS to give you hints about its internal procedures. You've discovered the limits of that approach.

You could add procedural stuff to your application, in which you tag each row you process, perhaps with a `date_processed` column. Once you've done that, you can use SQL to declare a resultset that shows you the relevance-aging of data.

Or you could figure out another way to declare relevance, perhaps based on the aging of records that already have `date_created` columns or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ollie. I am not directly looking at any declarative characteristics of a database here. I am coming from the declarative corner since my workload is given in SQL.
But the measures I'd like to take are probably hidden deep down in the code.

I am not looking for a declarative way to find the answer (it would not make sense, since my question directly aims at the procedural execution of a query). All I need would be a simple log, which says query ```xy``` accessed rows [100, 102, 104].

Comment: The RDBMSs I know about don't have what you'r asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the party. But based on your question, this can be done easily in Postgresql

```
rahul=# select count(*) , array_agg(col1) from nametest where year > 1990 limit 2 ;
 count | array_agg 
-------+-----------
     3 | {5,6,7}
(1 row)
```

array_agg provides the list of the rows that have been processed.

Comment: If I understand that function right it returns data only of returned tuples, but not intermediate tuples.
In your example query, the scan should usually yield all the tuples in the table (assuming there is no additional index on year) to check for the predicate.